# CSS: Fixedsys font won't appear in Google Chrome browser

Tags: fonts, google-chrome

I'm creating a web app for personal use, and having the monospace font **Fixedsys** installed on my Vista machine, I would like to use it inside textareas (to show scripts). This works fine in Firefox using e.g.

```
#textfield {
    font-family: fixedsys, consolas, monospace;
}
```

... but in the Google Chrome browser, fixedsys is ignored and the next from the font list (here: consolas) is picked instead.

As I'm running into some other minor problems with Firefox, I'm pondering switching to Chrome for this, but can anyone tell me how to load Fixedsys in Chrome? (I can't even find it in the Chrome options menu...)

thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work in modern Chrome and Firefox as well. This is probably because Fixedsys is a raster font.

Comment: The answer how to make it work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14287746

Answer (score 0):

A strange bug, perhaps it is because Fixedsys is a system font and not present in your fonts directory?

EDIT: Also found this in the W3C CSS2 spec:

> System fonts may only be set as a whole; that is, the font family, size, weight, style, etc. are all set at the same time. These values may then be altered individually if desired.

Comment: It is indeed a system font, just like the "System" and "Terminal" fonts.

Comment: Where would I be able to find it, or how could I tell Chrome to use it?

Comment: You could try adding the free version of FixedSys to your fonts directory to see if Chrome can use it:
http://fixedsys.moviecorner.de/?l=1

Obviously that will only work for you, so if you want other people to view it later you might have a problem.

Comment: I tried this download, thanks, but it renders rather differently (and problematic) when I tried...